# R data frame to array json

Tags: json, r, dataframe

im have dataframe

```
id|name | surname
------------------
1 |James| Smith
2 |Mat  | Stone
3 |Stan | Daimon
```

im need convert this to array json object(just string)

```
[
{id:1,name:"James",surname:"Smith"},
{id:2,name:"Mat",surname:"Stone"},
{id:3,name:"Stan",surname:"Daimon"}
]
```

Comment: thanks,thanks,thanks

Comment: did you even google your question title? nope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `toJSON` from `library(jsonlite)`

```
library(jsonlite)
toJSON(df1)
#[{"id":1,"name":"James","surname":"Smith"},{"id":2,"name":"Mat","surname":"Stone"},{"id":3,"name":"Stan","surname":"Daimon"}]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, name = c("James", "Mat", "Stan"),
surname = c("Smith", 
"Stone", "Daimon")), .Names = c("id", "name", "surname"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```